# Why is an optical magnon with k=0 not an eigenenergy state?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, quantum-spin

I found in a paper the following explanation. Unfortunately, I can't understand it. Can anyone help me on this?

> In the limit of equal spins an optical magnon with k=0 gets an acoustical one at the
>   boundary of the Brillouin zone where it is known to have a finite life time.

Comment: Which paper is it?

Comment: @Qmechanic [This one](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/pssb.19690360263/abstract).

Comment: See: [Energy renormalisation and damping of surface spin waves in Heisenberg ferromagnets](https://encrypted.google.com/url?q=https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/jpa-00224166/document&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiawo_FtszaAhUK6GMKHf_OD3UQFggQMAA&usg=AOvVaw3rfvhzMzQQz6pnKYw7WQWy) (short .PDF) by D. Kontos, M. Cottam. Or P12 "[Quasiclassical theory of spin dynamics in superfluid $^3$He: kinetic equations in the bulk and spin response of surface Majorana states](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.04468).

Answer (score 1):

What comes into my mind is the three-magnon process, in which an optical magnon with $k=0$ and $\omega=\omega_0$ splits into two acoustic magnons, one $k=k_1, \omega=\frac{\omega_0}{2}$, the other $k=-k_1, \omega=\frac{\omega_0}{2}$. Note that in this process energy and momentum are conserved. This 3-magnon process can lead to a finite life time.

Not sure.